# How to add Search Engine if target API is HoneyComb

Tags: android, api, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am trying to add a search interface based on the android docs. However, my target api level is 8, which is gingerbread (i think) but the eclipse, as well as the docs says the target api level must be 11 (honey comb). How could I resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by search engine ?

Comment: this. https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs page in the link you posted in your comment on your question it says...

> Note: Later in this class, you will learn how to make your app compatible down to Android 2.1 (API level 7) for devices that do not support SearchView.

You need to look at [Remaining Backward Compatible](https://developer.android.com/training/search/backward-compat.html) which uses the v7 compatibility library to supporrt back to API 7 (Eclair). BTW, API 8 is Froyo (Android v2.2).